# ListView is crushing Tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a Tab view and I have added a new ListView component on my project. The problem is that I have that ListView configure with flexbox and when I scroll down that ListView is over my Tabs and I can't click on them
[image]

What I want to do is that ListView be under the Tab Section and be able to scroll it.

Any tip about how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React native dose not have a z-index equivalent. Instead - the order of the components determines the order in which they will be displayed.

If you want the TabBar to be on top simply move the component to the end of the file.

You can check it online [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/OjzcxQ), simple change the order of the `View` and see how the order change accordingly.

**EDIT:** From version 0.30 z-index is supported by React Native as zIndex styles. Take a look on the [release notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.30.0).

Comment: Here there is some interesting findings we could add https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-overlay

Answer (score 0):

Try adding position: fixed to the component on the bottom, although in that case you need to specify it's exact location.

If this doesn't work, use flexbox to create a sticky footer, you can find how here: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/